# Access to the date details in a Django database

Tags: python, django

I'm currently going over the official Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/). At some point we're shown how to filter keys by the year of the the automatically-filled `pub_date` column.

```
>>> Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
<Question: What's up?>
```

But somehow the syntax when calling the `year` of the date directly has to be with a `.` instead of a `__`...

```
In [56]: q=Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)

In [57]: q.pub_date__year
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [57], line 1
----> 1 q.pub_date__year

AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'pub_date__year'

In [58]: q.pub_date.year
Out[58]: 2023
```

Is there some reason it has to be different when called outside of the parenthesis?

Comment: Within queries the "." notation is not possible, since only keyword arguments can used, therefore the "__" syntax is used as a kind of workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is **q.pub_date** is datetime object and it has the attribute called **year** in python, its the syntax that you can access the object attributes using dot(.) that's why you have to write datetime_obj.year to get the year.

Comment: Hii @Ariel C if this is helpful for you then can you please accept this answer as a accepted answer?